# Get list of person who shared a post on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I don't know if it is possible but how can I get the list of person who shared a post on specific page
For example I wanted to get the list of the person who shared this post

https://www.facebook.com/shares/view?id=1322453071112636

I don't think with graph explorer api of facebook is possible is there an other solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible via usage of [`/{object-id}/sharedposts`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/object/sharedposts) endpoint.

[Example query in Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=9445547199_10154511630877200%2Fsharedposts&version=v2.8) for [this post](https://www.facebook.com/Engineering/posts/10154511630877200) made by Facebook fanpage.

**Keep in mind that you will be able to see only shares from people that has granted your app permisions to view their posts. [[source](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1404733043148335/)]**

Comment: I think you have to be the owner of the page

Comment: No. Checkout provided Graph Explorer example. I'm not admin on that Facebook page, but I can see shares.

Comment: he just try with your method
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=169373263087295_1322453071112636%2Fsharedposts&version=v2.8
and I have no data

Comment: @user492642 it seems you can only see shared from people that have granted your app permissions to do that

Comment: I've updated my answer to include [this](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1404733043148335/) answer from FB developer.

Comment: Is there a specific permission you need to request from your user other than the basic permissions to be able to get a users shared post of an object?

Answer (score 1):

With the current version (2.8) of Graph API you can make a request like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/POST_ID?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&fields=sharedposts

Just change POST_ID to the post you want to get the shares from and include your access_token.

You can also select subfields which the sharedposts json object should contain. For further information see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/object/sharedposts or try out stuff via the Graph API Explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: I don't think it will work with all post 
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/913138225443874_1155908864500141?access_token=XXXXXX&fields=sharedposts

I am not the owner of this page