# Programmatically Access the list of people who shared a post in an Faceboob page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have seen a facebook page  p1 (Not my own page) , which has a post pos1  in it . I have to programmatically access the details of users who has shared the post .(I want details like when he shared and how many times).

I have gone through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39995819/1559331) 
and  tried out following request from graph API explorer ,

> GET /v2.8/{object-id}/sharedposts HTTP/1.1

in place of object id , I have used **pageId_postId**

But It returned an empty result array like the following

> {   "data": [   ] }

Note : I am able to see the same above mentioned data while logging in to facebook ,as a facebook user

Comment: _“But It returned an empty result array”_ - you would only get to see posts of users that have logged in to your app and granted it permission to see their posts in the first place. _“Note : I am able to see the same above mentioned data while logging in to facebook ,as a facebook user”_ - absolutely not relevant, UI and API are two very different things.

Comment: Thanks for the comment , I  didn't really get the difference in UI and API .In the UI I have logged into Facebook via a browser and on clicking the no. of shares (In the particular  page for that particular post) I was able to see the people who shared .Similar to that I have used a auth token  in Graph API Explorer along with post id and page id . So I was expecting that I could get the list of people who shared .Can you please explain

Comment: You are a single person sitting in front of the UI, and using it manually you might be able to get that info for a couple dozen or maybe a hundred links. Via API however you could request that info on a large scale for hundreds of thousands of posts, and you might even be of the “shady” variety like Cambridge Analytica ... so if that was possible, that would not be good. Therefor, UI and API are two “different animals”, in a lot of respects. Thinking “I can see this via the UI, so it must be available via API as well” is simply wrong in many cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data of users who did not authorize your App, or data of users on Pages you do not manage are none of your business. You cannot get their names (or any other personal data) for privacy reasons.

Comment: I didin't get what you mean by "your App" , I have used the Graph API Explorer to access the url. I could see the data ( which I was trying to access ) when I logged into Facebook from browser. Similar to that I have used an auth token from the graph API (Similar to login , right ?)

Comment: just because you see data on facebook.com does not mean you can grab it with the api. and the api explorer app is just for testing, always use your own app. anyway, what you want to achieve is not possible for privacy reasons. that is the main point.